# Integrating a proxy function with JuliaConnectoR

Tags: r, julia, juliaconnector

I would like to integrate a function defined in R with the 'QuadGK' module in Julia by using the 'JuliaConnector' R package.

The code I tried looks like the following:

```
library(JuliaConnectoR)
juliaSetupOk()
## [1] TRUE

fRunge <- function(x) 1/(1 + (5*x)^2)   # Runge function in R
jRunge <- juliaPut(fRunge)              # proxy function object
```

How can I call `jRunge` in the Julia environment, respectively, which name does `jRunge` have in the Julia environment? Attempts like `juliaCall("jRunge", 1.0)` or `juliaEval("jRunge(1.0)")` fail because the name `jRunge` is not known.

```
juliaEval("jRunge(1.0)")
## Error: Evaluation in Julia failed.
## Original Julia error message:
## LoadError: UndefVarError: `jRunge` not defined
```

With 'JuliaCall' the following approach works immediately, because the name "jlRunge" is assigned and known.

```
library(JuliaCall)
julia_setup()

julia_assign("jlRunge", fRunge)
julia_eval("jlRunge([-1.0, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1.0])")
## [1] 0.03846154 0.13793103 1.00000000 0.13793103 0.03846154
```

Now I am able to integrate the function in Julia.

```
julia_library("QuadGK")
julia_command("I, err = quadgk(jlRunge, -1, 1);")
julia_eval("[I, err]")
## [1] 5.493603e-01 1.058539e-09
```

Unfortunately, the latest R package 'JuliaCall' does not work correctly with R 4.3.0+ and Julia 1.9.0+ which is really a pity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass an R function as an argument to a Julia function that takes a function as an argument.

```
f <- function(x) 1/(1 + (5*x)^2) 
QuadGK <- juliaImport("QuadGK")
result <- QuadGK$quadgk(f, -1, 1)
juliaGet(result)
```

However, be aware that this will be very inefficient for such simple functions. The `JuliaConnectoR` package connects to Julia via TCP, and for each function call objects  need to be a serialized.
This additional overhead makes the `JuliaConnectoR` slower, especially in such cases.
But this looser coupling of Julia and R via TCP makes it also more stable across version, as you are experiencing right now.
I would advise to assign this simple function as a Julia function.
You can do the following:

```
f <- juliaEval("x -> 1 /(1+(5x)^2)")
QuadGK <- juliaImport("QuadGK")
result <- QuadGK$quadgk(f, -1, 1)
juliaGet(result)
```

This way, you define a Julia function and transfer only the reference to it into R, which is stored into the variable `f`. This will make the evaluation in the next call fast, as it will be directly in Julia.
It is also possible to define a function with name `f` directly in the Julia session like JuliaCall does. This way, a function with name `f` will exist in the Julia session. (You could also assign the returned function definition to an R variable `f`. Then you would have both a function `f` in Julia and in `R`.)

```
juliaEval("function f(x) 1 /(1+(5x)^2) end")
result <- juliaEval("QuadGK.quadgk(f, -1, 1)")
juliaGet(result)
```

I preferred the first approach because it creates cleaner code in my opinion.
If you are assigning variables in the Julia session, you have to keep two workspaces in mind. The JuliaConnectoR allows that you have all objects in the R workspace as references.

Comment: I will not accept your answer. My function is defined in the R environment and cannot be redefined in Julia (what you tried). The Runge function here is only a simplified example of some larger R function that is not available as an implementation in Julia. Therefore both your approaches are not viable. Sorry if my shortened example has misled you.

Comment: @HansW. I've edited the answer and added a solution for this problem that uses an R function and does not require `juliaLet`.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it for a while, I came up with the following
(though a bit clumsy) solution:

```
fRunge <- function(x) 1 / (1 + (5*x)^2)     # R function

juliaImport("QuadGK")
sol <- juliaLet("QuadGK.quadgk(f, -1, 1)", f = fRunge)

I <- juliaGet(sol)[[1]]
r <- juliaGet(sol)[[2]]
I; r
## [1] 0.5493603
## [1] 1.058539e-09
```

The trick is to make use of the quite powerful `juliaLet` command.

But I like more how 'JuliaCall' would handle the situation by defining a named variable in the Julia environment. Adding this feature to 'JuliaConnectoR' could be nice.

Comment: Using `juliaLet` in this case is possible, but there is a simpler way. You can simply pass R functions to imported Julia functions. I've edited my answer below to show this.

Comment: In retrospect I like the solution with 'juliaLet' better and better. Still, your hint was useful and I will give the well-deserved credit.